# StateHasChanged is not Rendering the component when even Action is invoked

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I'm trying to trigger StateHasChanged when the button is clicked. This is done by adding `StateHasChanged` to `event Action`. When debugging I can see that the `Invoke` method of the event is being fired but the UI is not re-rendering.

This is the flow I want it work like:

1. The button is clicked in `OgToolbar.razor.cs`
2. The event is triggered
3. `StorageManagerService` changes the state in the local storage and invokes the event
4. The UI is re-rendering in `OgSidebar.razor.cs`

**OgSidebar.razor.cs where the UI must re-render**

```cs
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
     StorageManagerService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var containsKey = await StorageManagerService.ContainsKeyAsync("isSidebarToggled");

    if (containsKey == false)
        await StorageManagerService.SetItemAsync("isSidebarToggled", true);

    _isSidebarToggled = await StorageManagerService.GetItemByKeyAsync<bool> 
                        ("isSidebarToggled");
}

public void Dispose()
{
    StorageManagerService.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
}
```

**OgToolbar.razor.cs where the button is clicked and triggers the event**

```cs
[Inject]
private IStorageManagerService StorageManagerService { get; set; }

private bool _isSidebarToggled = false;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    StorageManagerService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var containsKey = await StorageManagerService.ContainsKeyAsync("isSidebarToggled");

    if (containsKey == false)
        await StorageManagerService.SetItemAsync("isSidebarToggled", true);

    _isSidebarToggled = await StorageManagerService.GetItemByKeyAsync<bool>("isSidebarToggled");
}

public void Dispose()
{
    StorageManagerService.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
}
```

**StorageManagerService.cs where the state is managed in local storage using Blazored:**

```cs
private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;

public event Action OnChange;

public async Task<T> GetItemByKeyAsync<T>(string identifier)
{
    var itemFromLocalStorage = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<T>(identifier);

    return itemFromLocalStorage;
}

public async Task<bool> ContainsKeyAsync(string identifier)
{
    return await _localStorageService.ContainKeyAsync(identifier);
}

public async Task SetItemAsync<T>(string identifier,T item)
{
    await _localStorageService.SetItemAsync(identifier, item);

    OnChange.Invoke();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trigger the event but the state of _isSidebarToggled is not refreshed.

Roughly:

```
//OgSidebar.razor.cs

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
     StorageManagerService.OnChange += async () => 
       { 
         _isSidebarToggled = await StorageManagerService
            .GetItemByKeyAsync<bool> ("isSidebarToggled");
          StateHasChanged ();
       };
}
```

Using `async void` for the eventhandler is a little iffy.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I don't know how did this slide out of my mind. Thanks